# QGIS 2.0 WMTS Issue

Tags: qgis-2, wmts

When using a WMTS within QGIS 2.0 (using the "?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" addition) only one tile per layer is loading. The WMTS works in other GIS software and this problem would appear to be unique to QGIS 2.0. Does anyone know why this would he happening and if there is a workaround to this issue?